# Hi,I cant add procedure in crystal report design showing as failed to retrieve data error is that any solution please

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, crystal-reports

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test (V_ACTION  IN     VARCHAR2,
                                  v_cur        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
   IF V_ACTION = 'A'
   THEN
      OPEN v_cur FOR
         SELECT Q_ID,
                Q_dtls,
                Qry_qrystatus,
                Qry_deviation_stas,
                Qry_qrystatus
           FROM QRYDTLS;
   END IF;
END test;
```

[image]

I tested the procedure it is compile successfully and query was tested and it also running properly.This error I cant found out Why?Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Error you got (ORA-06550) suggests that

- procedure `TEST` is created in one schema,
- but you're trying to call it while you're connected to some other schema (which doesn't have privileges to access `TEST` procedure owned by someone else)

In other words, make sure you're connected to the same user.